# How to send Objects to WebService code behind visualbasic asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, class, serialization

I'm using a referenced web service in my project, I need to pass two parameters: my class named "clPerson.vb" and an ArrayList of another class to the webservice method.


In my webpage I need to do something like this:

```
Protected Sub WebPageSub()
    Dim ObjPerson = New WebPage.clPerson(84) '84 is IDPerson
    Dim ALDocuments As ArrayList = WebPage.getArrPerDocs(84, "T") 'this returns an arraylist of clDocuments class, returns all the documents that person 84 has, "T" is the identified for documents

    Dim wsSave As WebServiceExample 'WebService must save the data I Send.
    wsSave.InsertData(ObjPerson,ALDocuments) 'I send an arraylist and
End Sub
```

In my Web Servide, should work like this

```
<WebMethod()>
Public sub InsertData(ObjPerson As clPerson, DocsArray as ArrayList) 
    ' ..SAVE DATA
End Sub
```

note: clPerson and clDocuments are classes that are in my principal project and in my webservice.

Comment: What exactly is trying to send data to the web service?  A web page?

Comment: My web page has to send a class named clPerson to the web service, then, in my web service, the method must recieve the parameter sent by the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it instancing two classes (WebService.clPerson and WebPage.clPerson), then I assigned manually every attribute like this.


Then I add an Object() type attribute to clPerson class to can save the ArrayList of clDocument class and to can send just a parameter to WebService.

```
    Dim cont As Integer = 0
    Dim CodErr As String = Nothing

    Dim ObjPerson = New webpage.clPerson(84)
    Dim arrDocPers As ArrayList = getArrPerDocs(84, "T")
    Dim ArrObj(arrDeReq.Count - 1) As Object

    Dim ObjWS As New WebService.wsObj 'WebService Object
    Dim WSObjPerson As New WebService.clPerson
    Dim WSObjDocs As WebService.clDocuments


    For Each arrDeReqaux As WebPage.clDocuments In arrDocPers 
        WSObjDocs = New WebService.clDocuments
        WSObjDocs.ID = arrDeReqaux.ID
        WSObjDocs.DUI= arrDeReqaux.DUI
        WSObjDocs.PassportID = arrDeReqaux.PassportID
        WSObjDocs.LicenceID= arrDeReqaux.LicenceID
        ArrObj(cont) = WSObjDocs
        cont += 1
    Next


    WSObjPerson.FullName= ObjPerson.FullName
    WSObjPerson.Age = ObjPerson.Age
    WSObjPerson.propALDocs = ArrObj

    CodErr = ObjWS.InsertPerson(WSObjPerson)
```